# Paypal Missing POST Data

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the regular files from Paypal

THIS IS ZZZ.php

```
 <?php namespace Listener;
    require('PaypalIPN.php');
    use PaypalIPN;
    $ipn = new PaypalIPN();
    // Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
    $ipn->useSandbox();
    $verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
    if ($verified) {
        $response = "verified";
        file_put_contents("test.txt", $response);
        /*
         * Process IPN
         * A list of variables is available here:
         * https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
         */
    }

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

THIS IS PAYPALIPN.php (regular one from them)

class PaypalIPN
{

```
/**
 * @var bool $use_sandbox     Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used.
 */
private $use_sandbox = false;
/**
 * @var bool $use_local_certs Indicates if the local certificates are used.
 */
private $use_local_certs = true;

/** Production Postback URL */
const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
/** Sandbox Postback URL */
const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';


/** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
/** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
const INVALID = 'INVALID';


/**
 * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
 * should not be enabled in production).
 * @return void
 */
public function useSandbox()
{
    $this->use_sandbox = true;
}

/**
 * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
 * environments).
 * @return void
 */
public function usePHPCerts()
{
    $this->use_local_certs = false;
}


/**
 * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
 * @return string
 */
public function getPaypalUri()
{
    if ($this->use_sandbox) {
        return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
    } else {
        return self::VERIFY_URI;
    }
}


/**
 * Verification Function
 * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
 *
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function verifyIPN()
{
    if ( ! count($_POST)) {
        throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
    }

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2) {
            // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
            if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                    $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                }
            }
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }

    // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
    $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
    if ($this->use_local_certs) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( ! ($res)) {
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $errstr = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
    }

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $http_code = $info['http_code'];
    if ($http_code != 200) {
        throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
    if ($res == self::VALID) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I'm receving a message at the error log of my server that says:

```
[25-Feb-2018 16:46:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Missing POST Data' in /home2/laplatas/public_html/php/PaypalIPN.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/laplatas/public_html/php/zzz.php(11): PaypalIPN->verifyIPN()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home2/laplatas/public_html/php/PaypalIPN.php on line 72
[25-Feb-2018 16:47:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Missing POST Data' in /home2/laplatas/public_html/php/PaypalIPN.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/laplatas/public_html/php/zzz.php(11): PaypalIPN->verifyIPN()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home2/laplatas/public_html/php/PaypalIPN.php on line 72
```

I have tryed everything but no success, I have readed also that could be that my server is not allowing post requests properly but it's the first issue I know about that, and if so, How do I change these file to allow post requests?

I have also open a question in paypal community... the issue is common but nobody answers properly
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/IPN-PDT/Missing-POST-Data/m-p/1448349#M153

Comment: check the access logs and see if the hit is actually from paypal; you cold also check your paypla account to see if a payment was made at that time

Comment: @rtfm I'm still with the sandbox version

Comment: The messages from paypal have been sent also, and tryed again

Comment: WHY THE NEGATIVES??? IT'S SO OBVIOUS!??

Comment: have you tried the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Simulator (ignore the votes, they have no meaning)

Comment: @rtfm Thanks for answering man, I'm absolutely stack. Yes, I've checked it, al right. URL's seems to be alright to. I'm just using their code, I tryed with other piece of code from a Bosnian-herzegobinia guy and turns INVALID.

Comment: and don't mind the votes, it's just that if you know it, why don't you answer it?? super clever guys!

Comment: tbh I have had years of dealing with Paypal. It's shockingly bad. I would highly suggest going over to a fundamentally better made product with better usability, better error recording, better online documentation (that isn't stuck in 2006) and more features, [**such as Stripe**](https://stripe.com/docs).

Comment: thanks for selling Stripe in every post about Paypal Martin, the issue here is to fix a problem of Paypal not change the product, of course, I'm thinking to add another system, i like stripe Martin, but Paypal, it's this issue and seems that nobody has the answer, not even from Paypal...great!

Comment: I just test your IPN URL to check the status of the listener response but it turns out to be 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: Yes, that's the same answer I get even when I make the buying process, keeps of being a mistery!! 2 day on it! I have open an issue in every web page I can, let see...

Answer (score 0):

THANKS A LOT TO @Athrun Zara & @rtfm. I'VE GOT THE SOLUTION!!!!

If you find yourself with this issue, just check on your web server if they have dissabled the EMPTY post request, that's what was blocking the whole thing, not programming issues. The thing is that Paypal firsts checks if the adress is real with an empty call, that your web server will reject.

It's been more than 10 hours of work to the bin...well I have learn the whole process as an expert and open an unexisting and unkwon issue in every programming website.

Comment: Given what you've said, I know this might be a stupid question, but was it ever resolved? Ive been on the same maze as you have with this but Im still not getting it. Is it my host settings that need adjusting or some adjustment to the code? Ive tried echoing a white space after the HTTP 200 header and it doesnt change anything if thats what you meant. How did you eventually do IPN?

Comment: Same issue and no solution.  Can you clarify please?